# Inserting HTML tags based off the different paragraphs in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am using the following VBA code to insert HTML tags based off the selection type:

```
Sub InsertTags()
    Dim parEach As paragraph
    Dim rngEach As Range
    Dim strTag As String
    
    ' Process all paragraphs in selection
    For Each parEach In Selection.Paragraphs
        Set rngEach = parEach.Range 'grab the range of the paragraph
        
        ' Choose appropriate tag
'        If rngEach.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticLines) = 1 Then
'            strTag = "h1"
        If rngEach.Style = "Heading 1" Then
            strTag = "h1"
        ElseIf parEach.LeftIndent > 0 And parEach.RightIndent > 0 Then
            strTag = "blockquote"
        Else
            strTag = "p"
        End If
        
        ' Check if the paragraph is not empty
        If Len(Trim(rngEach.text)) > 0 Then
            ' Insert opening tag
            rngEach.InsertBefore text:="<" & strTag & ">"
            
            ' Move end point of range before end of paragraph
            rngEach.MoveEnd Unit:=wdCharacter, count:=-1
            
            ' Insert closing tag
            rngEach.InsertAfter text:="</" & strTag & ">"
        End If
    Next parEach
End Sub
```

However, when I compile the code, I get a `Compile error: Can't find project or library` with the `Trim` function highlighted. What am I missing here please?

Comment: Try your function in the debug window `?Len(Trim("  some text   "))`. Check in object browser is it available under `Strings` class?

Comment: It is working fine. It is returning `9`.

Comment: Your code works charm for me. Copy and Paste it from your post, maybe there is some difference between the two instances.

Comment: it's strange; I get that same error.

Comment: Open Object Browser and check for `Missing: something`. If found remove it.

Comment: Your logic is incorrect. An empty paragraph will never have a length of zero as it will always contain the non-printing end of paragraph character.

Comment: @timo The OP tests the `Text` property length. But this is really not 0 but 1. So simly change `>1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, when I compile the code, I get a Compile error: Can't find project or library with the Trim function highlighted. What am I missing here please?

Maybe the **Trim** is an ambiguity of the name, try to use Fully Qualified Name:

`If Len(Trim(rngEach.text)) > 0 Then` ⇒
`If Len(VBA.Trim(rngEach.text)) > 0 Then`

The **Left** function ... esc. sometimes does the same thing.

Comment: That worked perfect. However, i believe my logic is not working right. As i still see <p></p> marks for empty paras. For example:

```
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<p></p>
<p>Hello world</p>

```

Comment: @Nosail Then the most primitive method is just to use the Find to clear all of them.  `ActiveDocument.Range.Find.Execute FindText:="<p></p>",ReplaceWith:="",Replace:=wdReplaceAll `
, or if you only got to OP with plain text then just use the method ``VBA.Replace to do this would be more efficient. 
Would you need me to help you check out what might be wrong with your code? (This does not seem to be the original question you were asking)

Comment: Thanks Oscars. I will create a diff thread to understand why the logic is not working.